# Does not ignore db.sqlite3 file,even i specified in .gitignore in django project

Tags: python, django, git, github, gitignore

in my Django project,i have already .gitignore file in root as well in django project but when i fire `git status` or `git add .` It adding all `__pycache__` `db.sqlite3` in repository. i need to remove those two things from my project. please help.!

> I tried all things like `*.sqlite3`, `mom/*.sqlite3`, `mom/db.sqlite3` and `db.sqlite3` in my both `.gitignore` file respectively. But anything not work in any directory.

here is my main git ignore file **.gitignore**

```
media
*.sqlite3
**/__pycache__/**
*.pyc
```

here is my another git ignore file **.gitignore**

```
media
db.sqlite3
**/__pycache__/**
*.pyc
```

> **I also tried many possibilities from online resources but anything not working**

**file structure**

```
MOM-PROJECT(local Repo)
|
├───MOM (main project)
|   ├───media
|   │   └───media
|   ├───MOM
|   │   ├───migrations
|   │   └───templatetags
|   ├───userprofile
|   │   └───migrations
|   │       └───__pycache__
|   ├───templates
|   │    ├───MOM
|   │    ├───userprofile
|   │    └───base.html
|   ├───manage.py
|   ├───requirements.txt
|   ├───db.sqlite3
|   └───.gitignore [another created after main]
|
├───README.md
├───.git
└───.gitignore [Main]
```

**list adding file of git add command**

```
    modified:   .gitignore
    new file:   mom/.gitignore
    new file:   mom/db.sqlite3
    modified:   mom/meeting/admin.py
    modified:   mom/meeting/views.py
    modified:   mom/static/js/meetingtext.js
    ...
```

Umm Actually first i created `.gitignore` file in at **main** folder where `.git` folder(`in project`) exist. my media folder automatically removed and that worked fine. but when i added `mom/db.sqlite3` or `*.sqlite3` in main `.gitignore` it's not ignoring therefore i created **another** `.gitignore` file inside my project folder where `db.sqlite3` is exist. but that also not ignoring my `db.sqlite3` file

please suggest me what i need to do. please don't suggest me to use Smart-Git or any other GUI option. right now i m learning phase so i need all thing over commandline

Comment: For the ones listed as `new file`, run `git rm --cached` to remove them from the index—you've added them to the index (though not yet committed, luckily), so now putting the names into `.gitignore` does not take them *out* again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue but found out that my problem was that I had already tracked and committed the db.sqlite3 file in previous commit, which made it impossible for git to ignore when I later added it to the .gitignore.

I think this is not your case but maybe it can give you some hints towards a solution.

To untrack the file without deleting the local file I used:

`git rm -r --cached db.sqlite3`

After this, the .gitignore is doing the job as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *s.

If you specifically want to ignore the **pycache** and db.sqlite3 files,
just add

```
__pycache__/
db.sqlite3
```

to your .gitignore file. Alternatively search for django `.gitignore` files and sample from there.

If you want to know in depth on the gitignore file check out https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Thanks for answer, it not work till it adding the db.sqlite3 i give in my question see..